# Windows 10 IIS 10 Error 404 Resource Not Found

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have two websites on a Windows 10 Pro box using IIs 10. Both websites have their bindings set for HTTP, a hostname, any IP address and both using Port 80. IT has added a DNS entry that resolves the website hostname set in bindings. From inside IIS I can browse either web site. On the machine that is hosting the web sites I can open them just using the web site host name. However, on another machine on the  network you put in the FQDN of the web site and you immediately get a Error 404 Resource Not Found. When you do a nslookup on the FGDN is resolves correctly.

I am stumped. Anyone who might have an answer?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Use tools like Wireshark to confirm the requests actually land on the IIS machine. Besides, read IIS log files to learn the sub status code of such 404.

Comment: Lex Li, good thought on Wireshark. I have looked at the IIS logs and didn't get much. But will revisit them.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a new site in IIS! This time I made sure that the hostname was all lower case and matched the host name in DNS. I am suspecting that everything is case sensitive.

Doug